# Is there a way I can get this motion detector system on my laptop to play mp3 files?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, motion-detection

where it says "hello", it is said by a text to speech and I would like to replace that hello with an mp3 file (music). This being so that when I make some motion, a song will play. I don't really know what I'm doing so if anybody knows a simpler way to do this I would really like to know and I would not redistribute the code in any way. thanks

```
import cv2
import pyttsx3
import threading


# This funtion plays the audio message
def thread_voice_alert(engine):
    engine.say("hello")
    engine.runAndWait()


baseline_image=None
status_list=[None,None]
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Setting parameters for voice
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

while True:
    check, frame = video.read()
    status=0
    gray_frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame,(25,25),0)

    if baseline_image is None:
        baseline_image=gray_frame
        continue

    delta=cv2.absdiff(baseline_image,gray_frame)
    threshold=cv2.threshold(delta, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    (contours,_)=cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 10000:
            continue
        status=1
        (x, y, w, h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 1)
    status_list.append(status)
    
    
    if status_list[-1]==1 and status_list[-2]==0:
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_voice_alert, args=(engine,))
        t.start()


    cv2.imshow("gray_frame Frame",gray_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Delta Frame",delta)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame",threshold)
    cv2.imshow("Color Frame",frame)

    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key==ord('q'):
        if status==1:
            times.append(datetime.now())
        break


#Clean up, Free memory
engine.stop()
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I DID NOT WRITE THIS CODE. ORIGINAL SOURCE: https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-motion-triggered-alarm-in-5-minutes-342fbe3d5396

Answer (score 0):

You can use the playsound module. You need to install it with `pip install playsound`

Then just do

```
from playsound import playsound

# Put this wherever you want the sound to play
playsound('path-to-your-file.mp3')
```